# How to put a node in two views?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, nodes

I am using Swift 3.0, for IOS.
I Have designed a little circle node.

```
private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    // Create shape node to use during mouse interaction
    let w = (self.size.width + self.size.height) * 0.001
    self.spinnyNode = SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: w, height: w))

    if let spinnyNode = self.spinnyNode {
        spinnyNode.lineWidth = 8
        spinnyNode.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.0000001)]))
    }
}
```

When I use the self.addChild function, I want the node to be added to two views / scenes.

Maybe I can call the self.addChild function twice?

If anyone has any suggestions, that would be great!!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A node can only have one parentNode. You'll have to create two nodes if you want it in two scenes.

Comment: Well, could using the self.addChild function twice work then?? If it does, how would I specify another class or view to add it to.

Comment: You can call `addChild` multiple times, but you cant pass the same node object each time. You'd just have to duplicate your current code that creates a node so you're creating two nodes, then add them separately. If you have more questions, please include the code you've tried so far. "How to" questions are very difficult to answer accurately.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think that you actually answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create two nodes one in each view. Why would you want the same node in two different views? If its a game you should be able to code multiple levels in one view if that is what you are trying to do.